# immutable.js: Map versus Seq

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

What the difference between a Map and a Seq in Immutable.js? Can you please provide an example demonstrating the difference between the two.

Answer (score 4):

Immutable’s `Map` is an unordered `Iterable.Keyed` which consists of `(key, value)` pairs.

```
// create a Map()
const map = Map({a: 1, b: 'Hello'});
// get a value for a specific key
console.log(map.get('b'));
> "Hello"
// set a new value and assign it to a new Map()
const newMap = map.set('c', 'This is a new key/value pair');
console.log(newMap.get('c'));
> "This is a new key/value pair"
```

It provides access to a variety of methods such as `setIn()`, `deleteIn()`, `merge()`, `map()` and so on. It can also be converted to other Immutable datatypes. You can see the [the docs about all of these methods.](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map)

Immutable’s `Seq` is an Iterable sequence of values that does not need to have an underlying data structure. This is the first major difference from `Map` and you can see this in their definitions:

`class Map<K, V> extends Collection.Keyed<K, V>`

While:

`class Seq<K, V> extends Iterable<K, V>`

Right from the get-go we can see that `Seq` does not have keyed values, a major difference from `Map`. Another major difference is that you cannot append, update or delete elements from a `Seq` structure.

[In addition, to quote Lee Byron:](https://github.com/facebook/immutable-js/issues/218#issuecomment-64659297)

> A Seq is a lazy operation representation. You can think of it as a very light-weight container of a previous Iterable and some operation to apply (map, filter, etc), that operation is applied only when necessary to get a value. Seq doesn't store any values itself.

Because `Seq` is lightweight it can be rather performant for certain logic chains. The docs also note that it is often used to provide a rich collection API to JavaScript Object.

Comment: `Seq` also has the added benefit of wrapping the underlying data structure instead of creating a HAMT. A HAMT, although great for saving space when mutations are made (ie sharing data) - is less performant when you just want to store some data that will never change. So in that case, use a `Seq` over a `Map`